# TypeError at /flightdetails/airlines/1 'Airlines' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, url, view, model

I think since i am trying to pass only one object (id=pk),in airlines.html, for loop is not working. If I do Airlines.objects.all it works.Please help.

This is my view

```
def airlines(request,pk):
        content = {
            'Airlinesdata':Airlines.objects.get(id=pk)
    
        }
        return render(request, 'airlines.html', content)
```

This is my url.

```
 path('flightdetails/airlines/<int:pk>', views.airlines, name='airlines'),
```

This is my airlines.html

```
{% for order in Airlinesdata %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{order.Airline_Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.Email}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.Address}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.Contact_Number}}</td>


                    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting a single object you do not need to iterate.

Use:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{Airlinesdata.Airline_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{Airlinesdata.Email}}</td>
    <td>{{Airlinesdata.Address}}</td>
    <td>{{Airlinesdata.Contact_Number}}</td>
</tr>
```

You can iterate a list of object while using `filter` ex: `Airlines.objects.filter(....)`